# how can I fine tune Deplot model(VQA) + LLM model?

Tags: transformer-model, large-language-model

I was trying to fine tune DePlot model from huggingface(https://huggingface.co/google/deplot). It was able to load model and test with chart image to convert into table.
here is the result.
[Deplot test image and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG9tc.jpg)

Question is how can i use the result of decoded table to LLM model. if possible i wanna use with T5model for text summation and question answering.

Anyone can help me how to apply LLM to the deplot model?

I've tried to implement image captioning based on huggingface([image captioning demo](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/tasks/image_captioning)) but i got error and would u help me to resolve this issue?

here is the code

```py
# Load Library
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm, trange
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoProcessor, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
from datasets import concatenate_datasets, load_dataset

# Customized Dataset
dataset = load_dataset("/content/drive/MyDrive/sample_dataset", split="train[:90%]")
dataset

>Results:
Dataset({
    features: ['image', 'metadata'],
    num_rows: 54
})

# features 
dataset.features

>{'image': [{'id': Value(dtype='int64', id=None),
   'filename': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
   'width': Value(dtype='int64', id=None),
   'height': Value(dtype='int64', id=None)}],
 'metadata': {'image_id': Value(dtype='int64', id=None),
  'data_category': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
  'chart_source': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
  'chart_color': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
  'chart_multi': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
  'chart_year': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
  'chart_main': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
  'chart_sub': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
  'chart_text': Sequence(feature=Value(dtype='string', id=None), length=-1, id=None)}}


# Checkpoint, processor, model
checkpoint = "google/deplot"
processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
model = Pix2StructForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

def transforms(example_batch):
    images = [x for x in example_batch["image"]]
    captions = [x for x in example_batch["text"]]
    inputs = processor(images=images,
                       text=captions,
                       padding=True,
                       max_length=512,
                       truncation=True )
    inputs.update({"labels": inputs["input_ids"]})
    return inputs



train_ds.set_transform(transforms)
test_ds.set_transform(transforms)

# evaluate function
from evaluate import load
import torch

wer = load("wer")


def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predicted = logits.argmax(-1)
    decoded_labels = processor.batch_decode(labels, skip_special_tokens=True)
    decoded_predictions = processor.batch_decode(predicted, skip_special_tokens=True)
    wer_score = wer.compute(predictions=decoded_predictions, references=decoded_labels)
    return {"wer_score": wer_score}

# Training args
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer

model_name = checkpoint.split("/")[1]

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=f"{model_name}-ko-deplot",
    learning_rate=5e-5,
    num_train_epochs=10,
    fp16=True,
    per_device_train_batch_size=32,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=32,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=2,
    save_total_limit=3,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    eval_steps=50,
    save_strategy="steps",
    save_steps=50,
    logging_steps=50,
    remove_unused_columns=False,
    push_to_hub=True,
    label_names=["labels"],
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
)

# set trainer 
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_ds,
    eval_dataset=test_ds,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
trainer.train()

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-3435b262f1ae> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 trainer.train()

12 frames
<ipython-input-57-fda57d6f6ce9> in transforms(example_batch)
      1 def transforms(example_batch):
      2     images = [x for x in example_batch["image"]]
----> 3     captions = [x for x in example_batch["text"]]
      4     inputs = processor(images=images, 
      5                        text=captions,

KeyError: 'text'
```